# Rendering *only* drop shadow for image on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, core-graphics

On iOS, the CGContext includes support for rendering drop shadows using the setShadow() methods.  Is there a way to have the context render *only* the drop-shadow, and not the path/image that generates the drop shadow?

E.g.  I would like to make a function like:

`func makeDropShadow(shape: Shape)` which outputs only an image with the drop-shadow for the shape, and not the shape itself.

I would like the function to be versatile enough that it could also do:

`func makeDropShadow(image: UIImage)` to output an image with only the drop-shadow for the input image.  (e.g. if the input image uses alpha transparency, I want it to correctly produce drop-shadow for the image contents).

Any tips, libs, etc... appreciated.

Comment: What do you have so far? Have you tried setting up the shadow and then setting the stroke to .clear and then drawing? I understand that technically this isn't what you asked for but would have the same effect, would it not?